# Link to a script using 'dirname'

Tags: scripts, symbolic-link

I have a script placed in /opt/MyDir/myscript.sh which calls `java`, setting its directory as the classpath:

```
scriptdir=`dirname $0`
java -mx3g -cp "$scriptdir/*" MyApp.jar
```

I have created a link to this script in `/usr/local/bin/myscript` but if I run it, the classpath is messed up. Could anyone suggest me a workaround? How to deal in such situations? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you intend to use symbolic links for a script, the right way to get the real path of that script is:

```bsh
# Absolute path to this script
scriptpath=$(readlink -e "$0")
# Absolute path this script is in
scriptdir=$(dirname "$scriptpath")
java -mx3g -cp "$scriptdir/*" MyApp.jar
```

More about: [Reliable way for a bash script to get the full path to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself)